# localhost remove HTML extension

Tags: html, .htaccess, localhost

I've been trying to clean up my urls with htaccess but I can't seen to get it to work on my localhost.

My website url: localhost/index.html

This is the default htaccess file that's in my www folder.

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# To allow execution of cgi scripts in this directory uncomment next two lines.
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm .php
AddHandler cgi-script .pl .cgi
Options +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks
```

Comment: Please share your attempts, and their outcome. Even if they don't work, they show us that you have tried to solve the problem yourself and it allows us to tell what went wrong. See [the SO question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your `.htaccess` in your web root `/www` directory

```
Options +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.html [L]
```

Now `http://localhost/page.html` can also be accessed as `http://localhost/page`.

---

Note, that I had missed adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` before. This condition makes sure that any existing directory named `/page` doesn't get over-shadowed by `page.html`.

Comment: +1 but I would also add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` condition